# Is it possible to use a variable or parameter in a MySQL view?

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, view, parameters

I'm trying to create a View as following:

```
CREATE VIEW v_MyView
AS

SET @par_count := 0;  -- XXX Working in SELECT, but not in a View !? XXX

SELECT
    q1.day,
    q1.count_per_day,
    (@par_count := @par_count  + q1.count_per_day) AS count_sum  -- sums up count_per_day 
FROM
    (SELECT
        DATE(registration_date_time_obj) AS day,
        COUNT(Date(registration_date_time_obj)) AS count_per_day
     FROM  tbl_registration_data
     GROUP BY day
     ORDER BY day
    ) AS q1
;
```

The select statement itself works fine, just creating a view fails in MySQL since it doesn't accept user variables/parameters within it's declaration i guess.

**Is there a way to still create this view with a workaround for the parameter?**

Anyways, i'm able to create a similar procedure for the select statement, but that doesn't really solve the problem since i can't call the procedure in another select statement...

Thanks for your suggestions and solutions!  (:

Comment: For this purpose only we are provided with Functions. Try to create function so that you can use it in select statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) is pretty clear that variables are not allowed:

> - The SELECT statement cannot refer to system variables or user-defined variables.
> - Within a stored program, the SELECT statement cannot refer to program parameters or local variables.

You can do what you want using a correlated subquery:

```
 SELECT DATE(registration_date_time_obj) AS day,
        COUNT(Date(registration_date_time_obj)) AS count_per_day,
        (SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM tbl_registration_data rd2
         WHERE rd2.registration_date_time_obj <= date_add(date(rd.registration_date_time_obj), interval 1 day)
 FROM  tbl_registration_data rd
 GROUP BY day
 ORDER BY day;
```

Comment: Almost! ;) just the `WHERE rd2.reg...` line is not working. However, if i just use  `WHERE rd2.registration_date_time_obj <= rd.registration_date_time_obj` it works fine.

Comment: Now, if i need another `WHERE ...` limitation within both `SELECT` statements, how would that work out since putting the WHERE on the VIEW select only limits the outter select... :?

Comment: @webMac . . . You would probably need to put the `where` conditions in the subquery as well as the outer query.

Comment: I did and just for the specific select it works fine, but putting the origin select in a view and applying the where clause on the select view statement it only applies to the outter select statement within the view! In my concrete example i try to filter per year which i do have to do in the inner and outer select of your suggestion. Any idea how to solve that or do i have to create one view per year/where select? (not a good approach)

Answer (score 2):

Please read the documentation on VIEWS >> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-view.html

A view definition is subject to the following restrictions:

- The SELECT statement cannot contain a subquery in the FROM clause.
- **The SELECT statement cannot refer to system variables or user-defined variables.**
- Within a stored program, the SELECT statement cannot refer to program
  parameters or local variables.
- The SELECT statement cannot refer to prepared statement parameters.
- Any table or view referred to in the definition must exist. After the
  view has been created, it is possible to drop a table or view that
  the definition refers to. In this case, use of the view results in an
  error. To check a view definition for problems of this kind, use the
  CHECK TABLE statement.
- The definition cannot refer to a TEMPORARY table, and you cannot
  create a TEMPORARY view.
- You cannot associate a trigger with a view.
- Aliases for column names in the SELECT statement are checked against
  the maximum column length of 64 characters (not the maximum alias
  length of 256 characters).